# Blur text or words in posts for anonymous users

Tags: javascript

How can selected text, emails etc be **blurred and convert into image** to completely hide it. Like what quora. com does for guest users. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

How about the [Blurry](http://drupal.org/project/blurry) module?

> **Overview**
>
> This module can make your text fields blurry.

Comment: I missed that module... I will test and see if it works for me. Thanks for the link

Comment: It's just CSS. And text can be selected and copied.